# How can I increase amplitude without affecting frequency accuracy?

Tags: frequency, output, amplitude

[image: Scheamtics using bc547]I have generated a variable frequency generator which generates frequency from 0 to 10kHz, with the amplitude of 4.8-5.2 V. How can I increase the amplitude up until 8V without affecting the accuracy of the frequency? I have tried using BC547 transistor, 8V supply to the Collector, frequency signal of 5V amplitude to the base and the output obtained from the emitter. Looking at this on the oscilloscope, it is not as expected. The amplitude remains similar to input instead of increased to 8V, and the frequency accuracy is reduced.

Comment: USE AN AMPLIFIER.

Comment: -1 for the shouting.  Not reading the rest.  Show some respect to the volunteers here next time.

Comment: Generating a generator that generates seems promising. Perhaps you should post a schematic.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I'm deeply apologized but I dont think putting 'All Caps' meant that I was shouting. But I'm sorry if that is what you tought.

Comment: @replete I have included the schematics.

Comment: That isn't a schematic

Comment: HINT: To reach 8 volts output you will need a 10 to 15 volt source through a resistor. Your diagram shows a common buffer with current gain. You need to ground emitter and use collector to get voltage gain.

Comment: Ok I have got the solution. using LM741 OpAmp as comparator..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have tried using BC547 transistor, 8V supply to the Collector,
>   frequency signal of 5V amplitude to the base and the output obtained
>   from the emitter via oscilloscope is not as expected. The amplitude
>   remains similar to input instead of increased to 8V

That type of amplifier is called an emitter-follower and it doesn't produce any voltage amplification.

Comment: Ok I have got the solution. using LM741 OpAmp as comparator..

Comment: So your signal wasn’t a sine wave?

Comment: Jan it's a square wave